# How to determine the text font size in tinymce

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to when I click on the text, the font size of text in the editor toolbar to be determined. Such as Microsoft office word. How can I do it?

Comment: And what you have tried so far?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have not found the answer in Google Search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;
var node = editor.selection.getNode();
var fontSize = editor.dom.getStyle(node, 'font-size');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution to fetch the font size:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.queryCommandValue('FontSize');
```

Comment: If it works, I think this is a better solution.

Comment: @AliHesari Yes I checked it and its working fine